# Ask a solution to convert Chinese number mixed strings into English number strings

Tags: r

I am currently having a problem with some texts in my dataset, where it has Chinese and number mixed strings, and cannot be easily transferred and handled for later data processing. For example, in the date column, I have month-day written as --月--日， which corresponds to -- month and --day. Also, the column for deviation date, which describes how far it deviates from the average. 提前--天 means advance --days, 推迟--天 means postpone -- days. Is there a smart way in R that I can efficiently convert these Chinese and number mixed text into English and number mixed text?
Thanks
[snapshot of mixed strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwiH1.png)

Comment: You can take a look at the gsub function

Comment: Thanks, it worked.